# Remove a random amount of numbers in a matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm trying to make a small sudoku game in javascript.

My function does the following:

- calculates the amount of numbers to hide based on the chosen level.
- loops through the matrix and binds every cell to its coresponding HTML input.

  ```
  let initTable = (board, level) => {
  let table = document.getElementById('table');
  let amountToHide = calcAmountToHide(level);

  // populate HTML table
  for (let r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
          let input = table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          input.value = board[r][c];
      }
  }}
  ```

What is the most efficient way to randomly select `amountToHide` cells and hide them? By hide I simply mean to reset the cell's value to an empty string.

P.S. I assume every matrix has a single unique solution, hence I don't need to check for solution when hiding cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly fast to just select random values, and if not emptied yet, empty it and decrement the total values to hide counter, but you may want to store the emptied version in your own data structure, so you don't have to do a bunch of extra DOM searching.

So let's say you copy your board into `emptiedBoard`.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < amountToHide; ) {
    let randomX = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    let randomY = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    if ( emptiedBoard[randomX][randomY] != '' ) {
        emptiedBoard[randomX][randomY] = '';
        table.rows[randomY].cells[randomX].getElementsByTagName( 'input' )[0].value( '' );
        i++;
    }
}
```